# Three.js Import 3d Model

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

i have followed a couple of tutorials to import a 3d model. I have succeeded importing using A-Frame Tags, but when i try doing it with Three.js its not working. I have copy pasted the following code from a tutorial i found on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TeMXIWRrqE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8 />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script>
      let scene, camera, renderer;
      function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,5000);
        camera.rotation.y = 45/180*Math.PI;
        camera.position.x = 800;
        camera.position.y = 100;
        camera.position.z = 1000;

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
        controls.addEventListener('change', renderer);

        hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight (0x404040,100);
        scene.add(hlight);

        directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,100);
        directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0);
        directionalLight.castShadow = true;
        scene.add(directionalLight);
        light = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
        light.position.set(0,300,500);
        scene.add(light);
        light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
        light2.position.set(500,100,0);
        scene.add(light2);
        light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
        light3.position.set(0,100,-500);
        scene.add(light3);
        light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
        light4.position.set(-500,300,500);
        scene.add(light4);
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        
        let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load('Model/scene.gltf', function(gltf){
          car = gltf.scene.children[0];
          car.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
          scene.add(gltf.scene);
          animate();
          
        });
      }
      function animate() {
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      
      }
      init();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error it gives me...

```
    at new THREE.OrbitControls (OrbitControls.js:1101)
    at init (index.html:22)
    at index.html:62
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what is the error you are getting? This just gives the line, which isnt much help..

Comment: I am getting an error inside the OrbitControls.js. At this line scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', onContextMenu, false );

Comment: alright, but what does the error say? Is it undefined, null exception, out of range or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an argument when initiating `new THREE.OrbitControls();` It's expecting a `camera` and an `HTMLElement`, but you're only passing the camera. [See the docs here](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls). You can fix it by adding the renderer's canvas:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: Thanks, Mr Maquizzo. The Error Disappeared, but the 3d model still is not showing. No errors, only 4 warnings in the page.

Comment: Sorry, that's an entire different problem altogether. Feel free to ask a new question with a working example. Could be one of any number of things.